# [ROS1 Noetic]Qt5 Rviz plugin

Tags: ros-noetic, qtcreator, qt5, rviz-plugins

I'm having trouble making Rviz teleop plugin using Qtcreator. I'm using Noetic and Ubuntu 20.04.

The codes is not complete yet, for now I just want to see teleop GUI on Rviz. I'm using `catkin_make_isolated --install` build system

Error message:
`[ERROR] [1694503592.866043597]: PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class 'rviz_teleop_plugin/QtTeleopPanel' failed to load.  Error: Could not find library corresponding to plugin rviz_teleop_plugin/QtTeleopPanel. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.`

files:
package name: rviz_teleop_plugin

1. CMakeLists.txt
2. package.xml
3. plugin_description.xml
4. src/qt_teleop_ui,cpp
5. include/rviz_teleop_plugin/qt_teleop_ui.h

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(rviz_teleop_plugin)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs
  nav_msgs
  roscpp
  rospy
  rviz
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5OpenGL REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(QT_LIBRARIES Qt5::Widgets)

add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES rviz_teleop_plugin
  CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs nav_msgs roscpp rospy rviz sensor_msgs std_msgs
  # DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

link_directories(${catkin_LIBRARY_DIRS})

qt5_wrap_cpp(MOC_FILES
  include/rviz_teleop_plugin/qt_teleop_ui.h
)

set(SOURCE_FILES
  src/qt_teleop_ui.cpp
  ${MOC_FILES}
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${SOURCE_FILES}
)

add_dependencies(rviz_teleop_plugin ${PROJECT_NAME_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  Qt5::Widgets
  ${QT_LIBRARIES}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

install(TARGETS 
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/ rviz
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
)

install(FILES plugin_description.xml
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)

set_target_properties(rviz_teleop_plugin PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "rviz_teleop_plugin")
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>rviz_teleop_plugin</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The rviz_teleop_plugin package</description>

  <maintainer email="cabmintt@gmail.com">minseojeong</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rviz</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>

  <build_depend>qt_gui_cpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>qtbase5-dev</build_depend>
  <build_depend>libqt5-core</build_depend>
  <build_depend>libqt5-gui</build_depend>
  <build_depend>libqt5-widgets</build_depend>

  <build_export_depend>geometry_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>nav_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rviz</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>sensor_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>

  <build_export_depend>qt_gui_cpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>qtbase5-dev</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>libqt5-core</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>libqt5-gui</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>libqt5-widgets</build_export_depend>

  <exec_depend>geometry_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>nav_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rviz</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>sensor_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>

  <exec_depend>qt_gui_cpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>qtbase5-dev</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>libqt5-core</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>libqt5-gui</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>libqt5-widgets</exec_depend>

  <export>
    <rviz plugin="${prefix}/plugin_description.xml"/>
  </export>

</package>
```

```
<!-- <library path="lib/librviz_teleop_plugin"> -->
<library path="install_isolated/lib/librviz_teleop_plugin.so">
  <class name="rviz_teleop_plugin/QtTeleopPanel"
         type="rviz_teleop_plugin::QtTeleopPanel"
         base_class_type="rviz::Panel">
    <description>
      A Teleop Panel to control the robot.
    </description>
    <qtgui>
      <name>rviz_teleop_plugin/QtTeleopPanel</name>
      <class>rviz_teleop_plugin::QtTeleopPanel</class>
      <label>Teleop Panel</label>
    </qtgui>
  </class>
</library>
```

```
#include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QDoubleSpinBox>
// #include <QtWidgets/QPainter>
// #include <QtWidgets/QLineEdit>

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenu>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QStatusBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QSlider>

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
// #include <rviz/panel.h>

#include "rviz_teleop_plugin/qt_teleop_ui.h"

class QtTeleopPanel;

namespace rviz_teleop_plugin
{
    QtTeleopPanel::QtTeleopPanel(QWidget* parent)
        : rviz::Panel(parent),
        // : QWidget(parent),
          nh_("~"),
          cmd_vel_pub_(nh_.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel", 1))

    {
        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;

        QLabel* X_label = new QLabel("X ::");
        QDoubleSpinBox* X_doubleSpinBox = new QDoubleSpinBox;
        X_doubleSpinBox->setMaximum(1.0);
        X_doubleSpinBox->setSingleStep(0.01);

        QLabel* Y_label = new QLabel("Y ::");
        QDoubleSpinBox* Y_doubleSpinBox = new QDoubleSpinBox;
        Y_doubleSpinBox->setMaximum(1.0);
        Y_doubleSpinBox->setSingleStep(0.01);

        QPushButton* Send_Button = new QPushButton("Send");
        QPushButton* Up_Button = new QPushButton("UP");
        QPushButton* Stop_Button = new QPushButton("Stop");
        QPushButton* Down_Button = new QPushButton("Down");
        QPushButton* Left_Button = new QPushButton("Left");
        QPushButton* Right_Button = new QPushButton("Right");

        QLabel* Linear_label = new QLabel("Linear vel");
        QDoubleSpinBox* Linear_doubleSpinBox = new QDoubleSpinBox;
        Linear_doubleSpinBox->setMaximum(1.0);
        Linear_doubleSpinBox->setSingleStep(0.01);

        QLabel* Angular_label = new QLabel("Angular vel");
        QDoubleSpinBox* Angular_doubleSpinBox = new QDoubleSpinBox;
        Angular_doubleSpinBox->setMaximum(1.0);
        Angular_doubleSpinBox->setSingleStep(0.1);

        layout->addWidget(X_label);
        layout->addWidget(X_doubleSpinBox);
        layout->addWidget(Y_label);
        layout->addWidget(Y_doubleSpinBox);
        layout->addWidget(Send_Button);
        layout->addWidget(Up_Button);
        layout->addWidget(Stop_Button);
        layout->addWidget(Down_Button);
        layout->addWidget(Left_Button);
        layout->addWidget(Right_Button);
        layout->addWidget(Linear_label);
        layout->addWidget(Linear_doubleSpinBox);
        layout->addWidget(Angular_label);
        layout->addWidget(Angular_doubleSpinBox);

        QWidget::setLayout(layout);

        QObject::connect(Up_Button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_Up_Button_pressed()));
        QObject::connect(Down_Button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_Down_Button_pressed()));
        QObject::connect(Left_Button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_Left_Button_pressed()));
        QObject::connect(Right_Button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_Right_Button_pressed()));
        QObject::connect(Stop_Button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_Stop_Button_pressed()));
        QObject::connect(Send_Button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(on_Send_Button_clicked(bool)));
        QObject::connect(X_doubleSpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), this, SLOT(on_X_doubleSpinBox_valueChanged(double)));
        QObject::connect(Y_doubleSpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), this, SLOT(on_Y_doubleSpinBox_valueChanged(double)));
        QObject::connect(Linear_doubleSpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), this, SLOT(on_Linear_doubleSpinBox_valueChanged(double)));
        QObject::connect(Angular_doubleSpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), this, SLOT(on_Angular_doubleSpinBox_valueChanged(double)));
    }

    void QtTeleopPanel::on_Up_Button_pressed()
    {
        geometry_msgs::Twist cmd_vel;
        cmd_vel.linear.x = this->Linear_doubleSpinBox->value();
        cmd_vel.angular.z = this->Angular_doubleSpinBox->value();

        cmd_vel_pub_.publish(cmd_vel);
    }

    void QtTeleopPanel::on_Down_Button_pressed()
    {
        geometry_msgs::Twist cmd_vel;
        cmd_vel.linear.x = -this->Linear_doubleSpinBox->value();
        cmd_vel.angular.z = -this->Angular_doubleSpinBox->value();

        cmd_vel_pub_.publish(cmd_vel);
    }

    void QtTeleopPanel::on_Left_Button_pressed()
    {
        geometry_msgs::Twist cmd_vel;
        cmd_vel.linear.x = 0.0;
        cmd_vel.angular.z = this->Angular_doubleSpinBox->value();

        cmd_vel_pub_.publish(cmd_vel);
    }

    void QtTeleopPanel::on_Right_Button_pressed()
    {
        geometry_msgs::Twist cmd_vel;
        cmd_vel.linear.x = 0.0;
        cmd_vel.angular.z = -this->Angular_doubleSpinBox->value();

        cmd_vel_pub_.publish(cmd_vel);
    }

    void QtTeleopPanel::on_Stop_Button_pressed()
    {
        geometry_msgs::Twist cmd_vel;
        cmd_vel.linear.x = 0.0;
        cmd_vel.angular.z = 0.0;

        cmd_vel_pub_.publish(cmd_vel);
    }

    void QtTeleopPanel::on_Send_Button_clicked(bool checked)
    {
    }

    void QtTeleopPanel::on_X_doubleSpinBox_valueChanged(double arg1)
    {
    }

    void QtTeleopPanel::on_Y_doubleSpinBox_valueChanged(double arg1)
    {
    }

    void QtTeleopPanel::on_Linear_doubleSpinBox_valueChanged(double arg1)
    {
    }

    void QtTeleopPanel::on_Angular_doubleSpinBox_valueChanged(double arg1)
    {
    }

} // namespae

#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(rviz_teleop_plugin::QtTeleopPanel, rviz::Panel)
```

```
/********************************************************************************
** Form generated from reading UI file 'qt_teleop.ui'
**
** Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.12.8
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
********************************************************************************/

// #ifndef QT_TELEOP_UI_H
// #define QT_TELEOP_UI_H

#ifndef QT_TELEOP_UI_H
#define QT_TELEOP_UI_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QDoubleSpinBox>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenu>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QStatusBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QSlider>
#include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>


#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <rviz/panel.h>

// QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

namespace rviz_teleop_plugin
{
    // class QtTeleopPanel : public QWidget
    class QtTeleopPanel : public rviz::Panel
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        QtTeleopPanel(QWidget *parent = 0);
        // ~QtTeleopPanel();

    public Q_SLOTS:
        void on_Up_Button_pressed();
        void on_Down_Button_pressed();
        void on_Left_Button_pressed();
        void on_Right_Button_pressed();
        void on_Stop_Button_pressed();
        void on_Send_Button_clicked(bool checked);
        void on_X_doubleSpinBox_valueChanged(double arg1);
        void on_Y_doubleSpinBox_valueChanged(double arg1);
        void on_Linear_doubleSpinBox_valueChanged(double arg1);
        void on_Angular_doubleSpinBox_valueChanged(double arg1);

    private:
        ros::NodeHandle nh_;
        ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub_;

        QWidget *centralwidget;
        QLabel *X_label;
        QDoubleSpinBox *X_doubleSpinBox;
        QLabel *Y_label;
        QDoubleSpinBox *Y_doubleSpinBox;
        QPushButton *Send_Button;
        QPushButton *Up_Button;
        QPushButton *Stop_Button;
        QPushButton *Down_Button;
        QPushButton *Left_Button;
        QPushButton *Right_Button;
        QDoubleSpinBox *Linear_doubleSpinBox;
        QLabel *Linear_label;
        QLabel *Angular_label;
        QDoubleSpinBox *Angular_doubleSpinBox;
        QMenuBar *menubar;
        QMenu *menuteleop_panel;
        QStatusBar *statusbar;
    };

} // end namespace

// QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // QT_TELEOP_UI_H
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A plugin for a ros node (which rviz is) is usually not built using an isolated build. I suggest that you review the `TeleopPanel` rviz tutorial at this url (but ignore the part where it refers to the older `rosmake` command):

http://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/

The fully buildable code is available at:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials.git

It builds with catkin_make. Make sure you are using the correct branch e.g. noetic-devel.

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved it. thanku!!!!